# Is it possible to maintain a max rank with all six syndicates?

Tags: warframe

There are a total of six syndicates currently available to side with in Waframe since the Proxy Wars addition. However, due to their allegiances and conflicts, raising standing with one allied syndicate (via wearing the appropriate sigil) will decrease standing with two other syndicates. By switching what sigils I have equipped around, I can control what standings go up and down per mission.

So, I was curious. is it possible, through micromanaging, to maintain a max standing with all of the six syndicates. I know it's not too difficult to accomplish with three, and a little bit more challenging with four. But, five or six?

Comment: I don't believe so. I read somewhere that there is a cap you reach where it is mathematically impossible to increase with any syndicates rep without decreasing another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the love/hate standing of the syndicate this is not possible. See the following chart

[image]

Edit: As you can see three syndicates are neutral to each other. So you can boost standing within those groups freely. Red Veil, New Loka and The Perrin Sequence are neutral to each other. Steel Meridian, Arbiters of Hexis and Cephalon Suda are the other group.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Code Clown. Guess I'll stick to keeping a good standing with 4 syndicates then.

Comment: @Marvon If you have all mods and from one syndicate you could change to the next.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought ,but with the emblems available in the higher tiers that increase rep gained by a percentage, you would technically gain more rep than you would loose with the opposite syndicate, making having all six theoretically possible.

Incredibly time consuming, as you'd only be getting 15% of the intended reward per mission after completing the opposite mission, but possible.

Comment: Maybe the disfavor to other syndicates also rises with other sigils.

Answer (score -3):

It is definitely theoretically possible. New loka and Ceph Suda don't like each other, but you can freely get both up by doing an arbiters of hexis mission while wearing a sigil for loka. So hypothetically, you can do that with the Veil and PS as well.

Although in all honesty, Loka Seph and hex are probably the best 3 to get up. Their specters are really helpful for any solo player

Comment: Well, you can pretty much see how old the question is. The time of posting is shown in front of you. Plus, this is not really a 'thread', we're not a forum per-se.